# if else simple beginner issue

Tags: php, if-statement

Good day guys,

I've made a sweet favorites function with php mysql and ajax, and its working great. Now I want to show 'favorite' when favorite = 0 and show 'unfavorite' when favorite = 1

```
    if ($favorites == 0) {
    $favorite = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="favorite_button">Favorite</a>';
}

if ($favorites == 1) {
    $unfavorite = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="unfavorite_button">unFavorite</a>';
}
```

and echo it in the row as :

```
<div id="favorites">' .($favorite). ' ' .($unfavorite). '</div>
```

The problem is: when favorite = 0, both $favorite and $unfavorite are being shown. When favorite = 1 only $unfavorite is being shown correctly. Of course it should be $favorite OR $unfavorite. I assume the problem is clear and simple to you, please assist :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post the surrounding code as well? This should work.

Comment: In your description you're referring to `favorite` but your variable in code is `$favorites`. Typo? Please show the code that sets the variable `$favorites`.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($favorites)`? Does this also happen to be in any sort of loop?

Comment: Everyone, thanks a lot! Got the solution :) See Harmen's solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier to use just one variable:

```
$text = ''
if ($favorites == 0) {
  $text = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="favorite_button">Favorite</a>';
} else {
  $text = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="unfavorite_button">unFavorite</a>';
}

...

echo $text;
```

Comment: thanks a lot everyone for helping me out, Harmens solution worked :)  Learned something again! Have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check `$favorite`, you are using the wrong variable in your control statement.  Also, it is better coding practice to use `elseif` rather than `if` for that second `if`.  One more thing: it's easier to manage one resulting variable.

```
$output = "";
    if ($favorite == 0) {
    $output = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="favorite_button">Favorite</a>';
}

elseif ($favorite == 1) {
    $output = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="unfavorite_button">unFavorite</a>';
}

...

echo $output; // Or whatever you want to do with your output
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `$favorites` an integer?

Anyway try using three equal signs (`===`) or `else` instead of the second `if`:

```
if ( $favorites === 0 )
{
  // ...
}
else // or if ($favorites === 1)
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making a toggle, so you only need one variable:

```
if(empty($favourites)){
   $fav_toggle = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="favorite_button">Favorite</a>'; 
} else {
   $fav_toggle = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="unfavorite_button">unFavorite</a>'; 
}

echo $fav_toggle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Same code is working on me if I assigned $favorites = 0; or $favorites = 1;

You can also use if else

$favorites = 1;

```
if ($favorites == 0) {
    $favorite = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="favorite_button">Favorite</a>';
}

else if ($favorites == 1) {
    $unfavorite = '<a href="#" id="' .($id). '" class="unfavorite_button">unFavorite</a>';
}
```